# Can't use locals() in list comprehension in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, list-comprehension, scoping

The below works in Python 2 but not 3. Is there a way to access local variables in Python 3? Or an alternative solution to these cases?

```
[('{name_var}_{i:02d}of{maxpg:02d}.{date_var}').format(i, **locals()) 
  for i in range(start, end)]
```

Error in Python 3:

> KeyError: 'local_var'

Below is a simpler toy example of above (works in Python 2 but not 3)

```
local_var = 'hello'
['{local_var}'.format(**locals()) for i in range(1)]
```

Error in Python 3:

> KeyError: 'local_var'

Comment: Please make a clearer example for us, currently your code works in any version...

Comment: are you using some broken shell by happenstance? the `***` is not what the standard python repl shows.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I fixed the toy example to one that's representative and re-tested to confirm it works in Python 2 but not 3. The old one was only broken in pdb (for pdb-specific reasons).

Comment: On Python 3, the list comprehension has its own local scope. Variables from the outer scope won't show up in `locals()` unless the list comprehension uses them as closure variables.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry for my ignorance, but what do you mean by the list comprehension using them as closures - what would be an example?

Comment: @bamboo77: If the list comprehension contains a direct name lookup for variable `blah`, something like `[blah for thing in stuff]`, then the compiler will compile the code to go through the extra work needed to support accessing `blah` from within the comprehension. If it just calls `locals`, something like `[locals()['blah'] for thing in stuff]`, the compiler doesn't activate the mechanisms needed to support the lookup.

Answer (score 6):

As explained by @user2357112 in a comment, list comprehensions have their own local scope (and thus `locals()` dict) in Python 3.

Compare:

```
>>> var=1
>>> [locals() for _ in range(1)]
[{'_': 0, '.0': <range_iterator object at 0x7f5b65cb7270>}]
```

With

```
>>> [l for l in (locals(), )]
[{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'var': 1}]
```

In the first case, the function `locals` is called inside the list comprehension code while in the second the result of the function call is passed as an argument to the list comprehension.

The `dis` module confirms that:

```
>>> from dis import dis
>>> def f(): return [locals() for _ in range(1)]
... 
>>> dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7fc8173bd9c0, file "<stdin>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f.<locals>.<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              8 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `locals` function was not called. You see the call in the code of the list comprehension:

```
>>> dis(f.__code__.co_consts[1])
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                10 (to 16)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (_)
              8 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (locals)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             12 LIST_APPEND              2
             14 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   16 RETURN_VALUE
```

While

```
>>> def g(): return [l for l in (locals(),)]
... 
>>> dis(g)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7f5b65cb8930, file "<stdin>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('g.<locals>.<listcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (locals)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             10 BUILD_TUPLE              1
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `locals` function is called before the list comprehension execution, the iter is built and passed to the list comprehension.

Concerning your specific problem, you can force the evaluation of `locals` outside of the list comprehension (note the `i=i`: this is not a positional argument):

```
>>> d = locals()
>>> ['{name_var}_{i:02d}of{maxpg:02d}.{date_var}'.format(i=i, **d) for i in range(start, end)]
['VAR_00of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_01of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_02of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_03of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_04of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_05of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_06of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_07of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_08of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_09of01.2019-01-01']
```

If your version of Python is 3.6 or newer, you can use (f strings)[https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals]

```
>>> [f'{name_var}_{i:02d}of{maxpg:02d}.{date_var}' for i in range(start, end)]
['VAR_00of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_01of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_02of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_03of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_04of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_05of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_06of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_07of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_08of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_09of01.2019-01-01']
```

However, I think it's not a good idea to make a lookup in `locals()` for every iteration. You can build your `format_string` once and use it in the list comprehension:

```
>>> format_string = '{name_var}_{{i:02d}}of{maxpg:02d}.{date_var}'.format(**locals()) 
>>> format_string
'VAR_{i:02d}of01.2019-01-01'
```

Or (>= 3.6):

```
>>> format_string = f'{name_var}_{{i:02d}}of{maxpg:02d}.{date_var}'
```

Then you have:

```
>>> [format_string.format(i=i) for i in range(start, end)]
['VAR_00of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_01of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_02of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_03of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_04of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_05of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_06of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_07of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_08of01.2019-01-01', 'VAR_09of01.2019-01-01']
```