# Check if variables exist in locals()

Tags: python

I am encountering a weird situation.
I want to check if my variables `x`, `y`, `z` exist.

To do that, I tried:

```
>>> [var in locals() for var in ["x", "y", "z"]]
[False, False, False]
```

Then, I assign `x`, `y`, `z` to some values:

```
>>> x, y, z = 1, 2, 3
```

Nevertheless, I still have:

```
>>> [var in locals() for var in ["x", "y", "z"]]
[False, False, False]
```

But x, y, z exist one by one:

```
>>> for var in ["x", "y", "z"]: 
...     print(var in locals())
... 
True
True
True
```

Does someone have an explanation?

Comment: List comprehensions have their own scope.

Comment: Also: [Can't use locals() in list comprehension in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55084171/7851470)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See:https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comprehensions.html

> In Python 3, list expressions have their own scope: they are functions, just defined with a special syntax, and automatically called. Thus, the iteration variable(s) don’t “leak” out:

Reference locals() outside of the comprehension

```py
>>> my_locals = locals()
>>> [var in my_locals for var in ["x", "y", "z"]]
[True,True,True]
```