# Dictionary KeyNotFound

Tags: python, dictionary

Quick question for someone more knowledgeable than I - why does the first line of code work but the second doesn't? It seems to me I'm doing the same thing two equivalent ways, yet the {...} method throws an error while dict([]) method doesn't:

```
print dict([(key,locals()[key]) for key in ["Type","NoPoints","PointNos","Zoff"]])

print       {key:locals()[key] for key in ["Type","NoPoints","PointNos","Zoff"]}
```

Output:

```
{'Zoff': ['1', '1', '0', '0'], 'NoPoints': 4, 'Type': 'PANEL', 'PointNos': ['253', '254', '254', '253']}

Runtime error (KeyNotFoundException): Type

Traceback:
    line 143, in AddArea, "<string>"
```

#EDIT - I corrected the `key,locals()` to `key:locals()` (which is what I have in my editor - apologies for the bad copy/paste job I did there!) My error still stands though

I should also add that I'm using Python 2.7 (IronPython)

Comment: I think you need to use `:` instead of a `,` in the second print between key and value. Please check the code as it gives other errors

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed Please don't post answers as comments

Comment: @mcsoini sorry about that, the code doesn't actually run because `locals()` is specific. Was asking for a working test to provide an answer

Comment: @SiHa I've corrected a typing error which wasn't relevant to the error being queried. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the answer to this related question:
[Can't use locals() in list comprehension in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084171/cant-use-locals-in-list-comprehension-in-python-3)

> list comprehensions have their own local scope (and thus locals() dict) in Python 3

You can verify it by comparing like this:

```py
print(locals().keys())
print([locals().keys() for i in [1]][0])
```

The same thing happens for dictionary comprehension.

Plus, you would need to separate the key and value by a `:` instead of a `,` to make your dictionary.

## EDIT:

While this issue doesn't seem to happen for list comprehension in Python 2 (IronPython), this seems to be the case with dictionary comprehension :

```py
print(locals().keys())
print([locals().keys() for i in [1]][0]) # list comprehension
print({"test":locals().keys() for i in [1]}) # dict comprehension
```

Results:

```
['__name__', '__file__', '__doc__', '__builtins__']
['__name__', '__file__', '__doc__', '__builtins__', 'i']
{'test': ['i']}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is a `,` instead of a `:` in the second statement

when using Dictionary comprehension you need to follow this syntax:

```
{i : chr(65+i) for i in range(4)}
```

and when using the dict() command

```
dict([(i, chr(65+i)) for i in range(4)])
```

Source: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#semantics

Comment: Apologies - that was a mis-typing on my behalf in my post, but not in my original code. The error raised doesn't indicate the semantics as the error but that the instruction has been recognised and the key being searched for doesn't exist.

Comment: @Martial_Marlon that's alright, the answer by Uretki addresses your issue