# Python: How to get a variable attribute using a string value as the variable name in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Say I get the list of all variables defined  with `locals().keys()` and I want to get the attribute `status_code` for all the variables which name start with `request_`. All variables starting with `request_` are of `requests.models.Response` type.

I use a `for` loop and an `if` statement inside, like this:

```py
for x in locals().keys():
    if "request_" in x:
        print(locals()[x].status_code)
```

This would get me a list with all the `status_code` attribute for each variable.

If I would like to do the same procedure with a list comprehension, how would that look like?

I have tried this:

```py
[getattr(locals()[x], "status_code") for x in locals().keys() if "request_" in x]
```

Comment: No, it returns `KeyError: 'request_01'`, which is the name of the first variable.

Comment: list comprehensions have their own local scope (and thus a different `locals`). Here's a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084171/cant-use-locals-in-list-comprehension-in-python-3

Comment: It worked with `globals()` instead of `locals()`.

Comment: You should probably post that as an answer. Or close this as a dupe of the other one.

Comment: `... if x.startswith('requests_')]` is more robust

Comment: and the `.keys()` is redundant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't use locals() in list comprehension in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55084171/cant-use-locals-in-list-comprehension-in-python-3)